# Store user edited values in a log-table using PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Using JQuery I tried to rename the id or name attribute of the edited field and thought of recognizing it at PHP side, however I also use those attributes to update my table, so in that case it didn't recognize the new name of the edited field while updating the records. How do I deal with this? My code -

Jquery

```
$document.ready(function(){
var myname = $(this).attr("name");
var $inps = $('#myForm').find('input,select,textarea')
       $inps.change(function() {
       $(this).attr("name", myname + "-updated");
       });
});
```

PHP

```
$IDs = $_POST;
    foreach($IDs as $ID) {
       if(isset($_POST['$ID . '-updated'])){
            Update LOG-table
         }
     }
```

Comment: Seems like an X-Y problem. What is use case that makes you want to rename these?

Comment: Don't change the name of the field being edited.  Instead, add a hidden field that keeps track of the change, or better yet, the previous value.  Then process the hidden field(s) using PHP.  However, I wouldn't do that either.  In your PHP script you should fetch the data being updated, compare it to the $_POST data, determine what has changed, and then log those changes however you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dave Thanks for both the ideas, I used the second one and made a PHP function out of it. I used that function to record the values of changed fields into the table for all my forms. Let me know if you need the code. Cheers!